# El ultimo metodo esta correcto?Tengo que mostrar los objetos creado cuya fecha de sea de hace mas de 10 dias

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un trabajo para clase y tengo que hacer esto:

Mostrar los partes de trabaja que se hallen pendientes y tengan más 10 días de antigüedad. (puedes usar Datetime).

Los partes de trabajo tienen una fecha de creación. He creado el método pero no manejo mucho java 8 y no se si hace lo que debería de hacer.
Os dejo mi código (Es el ultimo método)

```
public class Empresa implements Serializable {

private List<ParteDeTrabajo> pilaDePartes;

public Empresa(List<ParteDeTrabajo> pilaDePartes) {
    this.pilaDePartes = pilaDePartes;
}

public Empresa() {
    this.pilaDePartes = new ArrayList<>();
}

public List<ParteDeTrabajo> getPilaDePartes() {
    return pilaDePartes;
}

public void setPilaDePartes(List<ParteDeTrabajo> pilaDePartes) {
    this.pilaDePartes = pilaDePartes;
}

public ParteDeTrabajo buscarParte(String nombreTrabajador) {
    for (ParteDeTrabajo p1 : pilaDePartes) {
        if (p1.getNombreTrabajador().compareToIgnoreCase(nombreTrabajador) == 0) {
            return p1;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public String aniadirParte(ParteDeTrabajo p) {
    pilaDePartes.add(p);
    return "parte añadido";
}

public String borrarParte(int posicion) {
    pilaDePartes.remove(posicion);
    return "parte borrado";
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String srt = "";
    for (ParteDeTrabajo p2 : pilaDePartes) {
        srt += p2.toString();
    }
    return srt;
}

public List<ParteDeTrabajo> trabajosPendiente(){
    List<ParteDeTrabajo> a = new ArrayList<>();
    long duracion = 0;
    LocalDate fechaHoy = LocalDate.now();
    for (ParteDeTrabajo p3 : pilaDePartes) {
        duracion = Duration.between(fechaHoy, p3.getFechaParte()).toDays();
        if (p3.getEstado() == 'p' && duracion > 10) {
            a.add(p3);
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

}

Muchas gracias por la ayuda. Creo que con esto termino ya el trabajo solo me queda el main.

Comment: Hola Carlos, tal y como te han comentado los compañeros en la publicación anterior deberías añadir el error que te da, para así arrojar un poco mas de luz al problema. Aun así, por favor revisa que hayas incluido todos los ";" parece que el ultimo método contiene un error de ese estilo.

Comment: Ya no da error por eso elimine el post, se trata de si hace lo que en teoría debería el método. El error era que me faltaban los paréntesis tras el titulo del método

Comment: Perdona la confusión, aún así te aconsejaría no eliminar las preguntas para que el seguimiento de las mismas pueda ser correcto y el resto de usuarios puedan seguir el hilo completo. Contestando a tu pregunta, si, el método es correcto.

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias